# Sein Haus und Garten ist/sind schön

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Which is correct grammatically?

> Sein Haus und Garten ist schön.
>
> Sein Haus und Garten sind schön.

I tend to think the former is correct by taking *Sein Haus und Garten* as a singular subject. Is this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter is correct. *Haus und Garten* refer to two tings so that is plural; as simple as that.

**Note:** The sentence is shortened. You could extend it to

> Sein Haus und sein Garten sind schön.

Comment: What about when adding *auch*? *Sein Haus und auch sein Garten sind schön*?

Comment: What about *Euer Gold und Silber ist verrostet, und sein Rost wird euch zum Zeugnis sein ...* (Jakobus 5:3-13, Lutheran translation)?

Comment: Gold kann aber nicht verrosten!! :-)

Comment: @stevenvh: Wenn du es warm genug machst...

Answer (score 1):

There is an old german song that goes...

> "Marmor, Stein und Eisen bricht"

even there it´s wrong, because it must be

> "Marmor, Stein und Eisen brechen"

in colloquial language you actually hear that a lot.
So if you make a mistake when talking to somebody, 
most german people won´t even notice.
But it´s still not right to use the singular here.

Comment: On the subject: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularis_materialis

Answer (score 0):

Like *marstato* says, you're talking about more than one object, so the plural applies:

> Sein Haus(1) und Garten(2) sind schön.

OTOH if you say

> Sein Haus mit Garten ist schön.

then "Haus mit Garten" becomes a single object, and then the singular applies.

---

Note: a common error in many languages is to use the plural form also for "a number" or "a lot":

> There are a number of options.

(Can somebody make this an example in German?) **This is wrong**. There may be many things (plural), but "a number" is singular. The correct form is

> There is a number of options.

You don't say

> Da sind eine Dose mit Murmeln.

either, do you?